# Do java caches results of the methods

Tags: java, caching, jvm, microbenchmark, jmh

***I use*** JMH to specify the complexity of the operation. If you've never worked with JMH, don't worry. JMH will just launch the `estimateOperation` method multiple times and then get the average time.

***Question: [narrow]*** will this program calculate `Math.cbrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` each time? Or it just calculate it once and return cached result afterwards?

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public  void estimateOperation() {
    calculate();
}

public int calculate() {
    return Math.cbrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

***Question: [broad]:*** Does JVM ever cache the result of the methods?

Comment: Where does `calculate()` come in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method return value is never **cached**. However, unnecessary calls may be **eliminated** by JIT compiler in run-time due to certain **optimizations** like *constant folding*, *constant propagation*, *dead code elimination*, *loop invariant hoisting*, *method inlining* etc.

For example, if you replace `Math.cbrt` with `Math.sqrt` or with `Math.pow`, the method will not be called at all after JIT compilation, because the call will be replaced by a constant. (The optimization does not work for `cbrt`, because it is a rare method and it falls to a native call which is not intrinsified by JVM).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're talking about with the JIT optimizations... `Math.sqrt()` also delegates to a native call (from the code I'm looking at, at least), and I don't see why the JIT compiler couldn't also optimize `Math.cbrt()` in the same manner as `Math.sqrt()` -- the same technique should work in both cases.

Comment: @user3580294 These calls may or may not be optimized depending on JVM. If we talk about HotSpot (the most popular JVM included in OpenJDK and Oracle JDK), `Math.sqrt` will be optimized, because it is a [JVM intrinsic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function), i.e. JIT compiler does not treat it like a method, but replaces the call with evaluation code in-line. `Math.cbrt` though is not a HotSpot intrinsic - it just was not made such because of its rarity and the absense of corresponding CPU instruction.

Comment: The call is not replaced with a constant. When I tested this, it called it every time.

Comment: @AnubianNoob How did you test this? I support OP in using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) - it often gives you realistic results.

Comment: I ran it and checked the times. `for (int i=0;i<Math.pow(10000,2);i++)` took WAY longer than `for (int i=0;i<10000*10000;i++)`.

Comment: @AnubianNoob It's not an equivalent replacement. Try `(int) Math.pow(10000, 2)`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I did. I casted to int.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Still slow with `(int)`? Hmm. Works equally fast for me. Would you mind sharing the whole test?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Simply put, Java does not cache method results, since methods can return different values every time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will invoke that code everytime it is being called

```
public int calculate() {
    return Math.cbrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}


public double calculate();
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #3                  // double 2.147483647E9d
       3: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Math.cbrt:(D)D
       6: dreturn
```

to have cache, simply replace that magic number by

private static final field

```
private static final double NUMBER = Math.cbrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: The bytecode does not explain anything. E.g. replace `cbrt` with `sqrt` and the method WILL NOT be called every time. The answer depends on the method being called and the environment. JIT optimizations ([inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) + [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) + [intrinsics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function)) may result in the call being eliminated and replaced with a constant.

Comment: @apangin so can you post your answer please?

Comment: @V_B Sure. Added an expanded answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to narrow question: It depends on the JVM implementation and how the code is interpreted.

Answer to broad question: No since, as Anubian also pointed out, methods can return different values on each call.